Is the presence of a specific gene in one bacterial species enough to conclude it has the same function in another species within the same genus?
I was wondering if the answer should be more or less conclusive given the following givens and some of their implications that I feel by gut feeling could play a role in the answer:

The species belong to bacteria:
Bacteria have higher genetic diversity than most plants and animals, yet some bacterial species belonging to the same genus can't be easily differentiated phenotypically.
The two species belong to the same genus
The genes I'm interested in are those encoding virulence factors, for example:

A. baumannii possesses a chaperone-usher pilus system, known as Csu pili, which facilitates the adherence of Acinetobacter baumannii to some surfaces.

In addition, all strains possessed the two genes that code for BfmRS
(except ATCC_19194, where only the bfmR gene was detected), a
two-component system that regulates Csu (Chaperone-usher) pili, which
are important for biofilm formation, adherence to abiotic surfaces,
and capsule production (Weber et al., 2016; Lee et al., 2017).
However, most of the Csu pilus components were annotated as
hypothetical proteins (CsuA/B, CsuC, and CsuE).
Chromosome Architecture and Gene Content of the Emergent Pathogen Acinetobacter haemolyticus https://doi.org/10.3389/fmicb.2020.00926

Is this enough to say that the Csu pili is one of the virulence factors of Acinetobacter haemolyticus as in Acinetobacter baumannii?
Edit:
If Acinetobacter baumanii is known to have a certain virulence factor, why is it assumed that all A. baumanii strains, as implied from text referring to such strains by A. baumanii period, have it?
What i want to say is that there could be, at some level, the capability of a working interpolation.
